# React Navigation 4.x to React Navigation 5.x

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

The current problem I have is that i want to [use navigation parameters to update the state](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/getting-started-with-react-native-and-expo-using-hooks-in-2020-fb466c25b04c)

The tutorial in the link above uses React Navigation 4.x while I use React Navigation 5.x

Tutorial:

```
function onSaveNote() {
    navigation.state.params.addNote({ noteTitle, noteValue })
    navigation.goBack()
  }
```

MyProject:

```
function onSaveAuction() {
    
    navigation.navigate('Home', { auctionTitle, auctionValue }
    

  }
```

This is the [warning](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state) I would get whenever I used used the code for 4.x

I have tried using the second bullet point which is to use `navigate` instead but it still does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax(except for the bracket you forgot to close). Your problem is with the data you are trying to pass. The warning tells you that you are trying to pass non-serializable values such as class instances, functions etc. So check again what are the values of auctionTitle and auctionValue.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know your data, however you shouldn't pass functions or class in nav params.

To make sure that your data doesn't have non-serializable data, as mentioned above, you can try do a `JSON.stringify()`, then `JSON.parse` in next screen to see if this warning disappears.

The best solution is to check your data, but if you need to pass non-serializable data, feel free to use JSON.

I made a example to you:

Passing params:

```js
function onSaveAuction() {
  /* It will remove any functions, class or other non-serializable from params. */
  const data = JSON.stringify({ auctionTitle, auctionValue });

  navigation.navigate('Home', { data });
}
```

Home.js

```js
function Home({ route, navigation }) {
  /* Get the param, then parse to object */
  const data = JSON.parse(route.params.data);
}
```